# Problema al guardar en una base de datos

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día, no he conseguido guardar el campo hora en una base de datos php my admin, el código para obtener la hora esta hecho en Javascript

```
<table name = "HORA"  style ="width: 250px; height: 24px; position:absolute;left:885px; top:185px;" id="reloj" border='0'>
<tr>
<td><div  id='hora'></div></td>
<td><div>:</div></td>
<td><div id='minuto'></div></td>
<td><div>:</div></td>
<td><div id='segundo'></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
Reloj();
function Reloj() {
var tiempo = new Date();
var hora = tiempo.getHours();
var minuto = tiempo.getMinutes();
var segundo = tiempo.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = hora;
document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = minuto;
document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = segundo;
setTimeout('Reloj()', 1000);
str_hora = new String(hora);
if (str_hora.length == 1) {
document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = '0' + hora;
}
str_minuto = new String(minuto);
if (str_minuto.length == 1) {
document.getElementById('minuto').innerHTML = '0' + minuto;
}
str_segundo = new String(segundo);
if (str_segundo.length == 1) {
document.getElementById('segundo').innerHTML = '0' + segundo;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola django, el titulo es un resumen de pocas palabras de tu problema, no debe ser un enunciado, para ello SO te deja un espacio y ademas una plantilla para realizar tu pregunta de forma adecuada. Te recomiendo leer lo siguiente: [ask]

Comment: Muy bien, gracias